# How do I set a conditional breakpoint on a specific table row using lldb?

Tags: xcode, debugging, uitableview, lldb

In Xcode, I want to breakpoint on a specific table row request in the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using lldb:

[image]

For example, let's say I want to breakpoint on the 44th row of `indexPath.row`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Condition` field, enter in the condition as follows:
[image]

where the debugger will stop on `indexPath.row == 44`.

Note that an alternative way to do this would be to set the `Ignore` field value to `44`. However that doesn't offer the flexibility that a condition does to stop on a specific `indexPath` row or section.